# Two TrackBar mirror

Tags: delphi, pascal, trackbar

I would like to know how to make my second trackbar.position mirror in the opposite direction of trackbar1.position. 
eg. 
Range from 1 to 100.

So When `TrackBar1.Position := 2`, then `trackbar2.Position := 99`
Regardless of which way the trackbars goes, I would like to mirror in the opposite direction.

Heres my code so far: (not interested in using keys to do this), just mouse interaction.

```
Direction : string; 
Skip : boolean;

procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
if TrackBar1.Position = TrackBar2.Position then
begin
if Direction = 'up' then   TrackBar2.Position := TrackBar2.Position + 1;
if Direction = 'down' then TrackBar2.Position := TrackBar2.Position - 1;
skip := true;
end;


if TrackBar1.Position < TrackBar2.Position then
begin 
if skip = false then
begin
TrackBar2.Position := TrackBar2.Position - 1;
Direction := 'down';
end;
end
else
begin
if skip = false then
begin
TrackBar2.Position := TrackBar2.Position + 1;
Direction := 'up';
end;
end;
end;
```

Im probably overdoing this. Maybe there is a simpler way. I prefer the simpler way.
Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 trackbars `OnChange` events are linked to this code:

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBarChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  tbSource, tbTarget: TTrackBar;
begin
  if Sender = TrackBar1 then // Check the Trackbar which triggers the event
  begin
    tbSource := TrackBar1;
    tbTarget := TrackBar2;
  end
  else
  begin
    tbSource := TrackBar2;
    tbTarget := TrackBar1;
  end;
  tbTarget.OnChange := nil;                           // disable the event on the other trackbar
  tbTarget.Position := tbSource.Max + tbSource.Min - tbSource.Position; // set the position on the other trackbar
  tbTarget.OnChange := TrackBarChange;                // define the event back to the other trackbar

  // Call a function or whatever after this line if you need to do something when it changes
//  lbl1.Caption := IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
//  lbl2.Caption := IntToStr(TrackBar2.Position);
end;
```

**Alternative start** (suggested by Ken White and comments from me ;o)):

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBarChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  tbSource, tbTarget: TTrackBar;
begin
//  if Sender is TTrackBar then      // is it called 'from' a trackbar?
//  begin
    tbSource := TTrackBar(Sender); // Set the source

    if tbSource = TrackBar1 then   // Check the Trackbar which triggers the event
      tbTarget := TrackBar2
    else
      tbTarget := TrackBar1;

    tbTarget.OnChange := nil;                                             // disable the event on the other trackbar
    tbTarget.Position := tbSource.Max + tbSource.Min - tbSource.Position; // set the position on the other trackbar
    tbTarget.OnChange := TrackBarChange;                                  // define the event back to the other trackbar

    // Call a function or whatever after this line if you need to do something when it changes
//    lbl1.Caption := IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
//    lbl2.Caption := IntToStr(TrackBar2.Position);
//  end;
end;
```

Comment: `tbTo.Position := 100 - tbFrom.Position + 1;` (1-100,2-99)

Comment: @teran: I have used `min := 0` & `max := 100`... this is why ;o) but I update to answer the **exact** question ;o)

Comment: @Whiler :) Ben, note that up/down/left/right arrows work without any code

Comment: @Ben: you're welcome (as you are new on StackOverflow... I explain, just in case... on left part of the answers/questions... there's a counter... to vote +1 if it's ok, -1, if it's not... and below, you can Accept an answer if it's what you are expecting...)

Comment: +1. You can simplify your variable assignments, though: `tbSource := TTrackBar(Sender); if tbSource = TrackBar1 then tbTarget := TrackBar2 else tbTarget := TrackBar1;`